# Replace text in CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, string, ckeditor

I need to replace some text with the same text, wrapped in a `<span>` tag so that it gets highlighted in the editor, yelp.

```
   var variable = "car";
   var text = CKEDITOR.instances.textEditor.getData();

   text.replace(variable, '<span class="marker">'+ variable +'</span>');

   CKEDITOR.instances.textEditor.setData(text);
```

FIXED

I had to assign it to text. Strings are immutable apparently, solution:

```
text = text.replace(variable, '<span class="marker">'+ variable +'</span>');
```

Comment: Please add some details about the problem you are having or the error you are receiving. See [ask].

Comment: i dont get an error, the problem is that the text doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change the variable text to texto, something will happen. Because you don't have a variable named texto. You also need the variable 'variable' to be declared.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerText.replace("your text/code","your text/code")
```

Comment: What is the difference between .editorTexto, and .textEditor. If those are supposed to be the same things, I think you should change those names, I think the function name should be textEditor() instead of editorTexto()

Comment: Nope, the text doesn't change